# Selenium Web Driver - Java - TestNG - Assert.assertEquals how to compare actual result with the range between expected result

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver

I have test scenario where actual result is fix percentage For example 135.68% but I want to compare actual result with the Expected result which is in range For example 130.00 to 136.00. If actual result fall between the range of 130.00 to 136.00 then test is pass otherwise test is fail.

I am using following Assert statement but no luck:

```
  import java.awt.Robot;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import jxl.Sheet;
    import jxl.Workbook;
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import org.testng.asserts.Assertion;
    import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;


    @Test
    public class TC20042 extends BaseClass{

        private SoftAssert m_assert = new SoftAssert();


          public void registration() throws Exception, InterruptedException {
                  FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("C:\\File\\Book2.xls");
                  Workbook w=Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
                  Sheet s=w.getSheet(2);


                try
                {
                for (int i = 0; i < s.getRows(); i++)
                {
                //Read data from excel sheet
                    String s1 = s.getCell(0,i).getContents();

    String xPath = "//*[@id='mainForm']/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]";
                    String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).getText();
                    double percentage = Double.parseDouble(text);

                    assertThat(percentage).isBetween(130.0, 136.0);

private Object assertThat(double percentage) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }   



    }

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                System.out.println(e);

                }
                }

    }
```

Comment: does `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app-banner']/div[1]/div/h2")).getText()` return the 135.68%?

Comment: Why not parse the text as double and `assertTrue(130.0 <= actual && actual <= 136.0)`?

Comment: YesShahid - driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app-banner']&#‌​47;div[1]/div‌​7;h2")).getText() return the 135.68%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used regular testNg Assert and it worked for me as below:

```
String xPath = "//*[@id='mainForm']/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]";
                String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).getText();
                text  = text.replace("%", "");
                double percentage = Double.parseDouble(text);   

                Assert.assertTrue(percentage > 130.67 && percentage < 135.69);
```

Comment: This was already presented to you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170029/selenium-web-driver-java-testng-assert-assertequals-how-to-compare-actual/39170860#comment65682759_39170029) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39170336/3429133). Furthermore, the interval you use now is not the one used in your question.

Comment: I did not use AsserJ import and code line is little different than what you suggested So.

Comment: My comment and Shahids answer didn't use AssertJ either, it was `assertTrue` from TestNG. The snippet might be slightly different, but semantically it's the same.

Comment: I saw that in the comment you mentioned but I did not notice your comment when I updated and again tried the code in my answer. And I also noticed that today you edited your answer So.

Answer (score 0):

Simply parse and check:

```
    String expectedPercentage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app-banner']/div[1]/div/h2")).getText().replace("%", "");
    double percentage = Double.parseDouble(expectedPercentage);

    // Do this parsing if range is in string format. Otherwise skip this block
    String range = "130.00 to 136.00";
    String[] numbers = range.replaceAll(" ", "").split("to");        
    double min = Double.parseDouble(numbers[0]);
    double max = Double.parseDouble(numbers[1]);

    Assert.assertTrue(expectedPercentage + " is not between the range", min <= percentage && percentage <= max);
```

Comment: Why would you parse the range?

Comment: because range is given as a string `"130.00 to 136.00"`

Comment: Hi Sshahid, in your code above how do you get text from the web. I mean you missed  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app-banner']&#‌​47;div‌​[1]/div‌​7;h2")).get‌​Text()

Answer (score 0):

Parse the text and assert the result:

```java
String xPath = "//*[@id='app-banner']/div[1]/div/h2";
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).getText();
double percentage = Double.parseDouble(text.replace("%", ""));

assertThat(percentage).isBetween(130.0, 136.0);
```

This solution uses [`isBetween(Double, Double)`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractDoubleAssert.html#isBetween(java.lang.Double,%20java.lang.Double)) from [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) as a [static import](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import). Alternatively, you can use the TestNG assertion I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170029/selenium-web-driver-java-testng-assert-assertequals-how-to-compare-actual#comment65682759_39170029).

Comment: Hi Beatngu13 - I updated code as you mentioned above but it show error - 'The method isBetween(double, double) is undefined for the type Object' Look like need to declare object ?

Comment: @Curious Then you pass the wrong type to the method. Could you please update your code?

Comment: Hi Beatngu13 - I updated code above but error is still displaying "Multiple markers at this line
 - The method isBetween(double, double) is undefined for the 
  type Object
 - The method assertThat(double) is undefined for the type 
  TC20042
 - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token"

Comment: @Curious Well, a) your `assertThat` statement has two closing parentheses and b) you defined the method yourself... you have to import it from AssertJ via `import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;` but I'm afraid you haven't downloaded the library either?

Comment: I cloned assertj core library from Git hub but there are many jar and I am not sure which jar to add into library.  I see one jar under doubles folder from the library I downloaded is "Doubles_assertIsBetween_Test.java" So only this jar is enough or I need to add all the jars under AssertJ library?

Comment: @Curious Don't you use a build tool such as Maven or Gradle? Checkout the AssertJ [starting guide](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-quick-start.html) to see how to add the respective dependency.

Comment: I added seperate pom.xml file and in that file I added following dependency:     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>                                   is this fine? and then I refreshed project folder. But the error "The method isBetween(double, double) is undefined for the type Object" is still displaying.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void assertEquals(double actual,
                                double expected,
                                double delta,
                                java.lang.String message)
Asserts that two floats are equal concerning a delta. If they are not, an AssertionError, with the given message, is thrown. If the expected value is infinity then the delta value is ignored.

assertEquals(133.00,expected,3.00,"ERROR")
```